# Floating point types representation

Tags: c++, memory, floating-point, precision, ieee-754

Is `std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559` + `std::numeric_limits<float>::digits == 24` enough to ensure(1) that `float` is binary32(2) in IEEE 754 ? Same for double with ... digits == 53 ?

1. In any case including the weirdest implementations still respecting the C++ standard.
2. "binary32" is a specific representation of floating points in the IEEE 754 standard, I don't mean "stored in 32 bits".

Edit : + `std::numeric_limits<float>::max_exponent - 1 == 127`

Edit : Are there any other ways ? If yes, which one is "the best" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use traits class to check your representation matches some expectations.

Here are the traits used to test your representation:

```
namespace num {
    template <std::size_t N> struct ieee754_traits;
    
    template <> struct ieee754_traits<4> {
      using unsigned_type = uint32_t;
      static constexpr std::size_t sign_size = 1;
      static constexpr std::size_t exp_size = 8;
      static constexpr std::size_t mant_size = 23;
      static constexpr std::size_t exp_shift = 127;
      static constexpr int32_t exp_mask = 0xFF;
      static constexpr unsigned_type mant_mask = 0x7FFFFF;
    };
    
    template <> struct ieee754_traits<8> {
      using unsigned_type = uint64_t;
      static constexpr std::size_t sign_size = 1;
      static constexpr std::size_t exp_size = 11;
      static constexpr std::size_t mant_size = 52;
      static constexpr std::size_t exp_shift = 1023;
      static constexpr int32_t exp_mask = 0x7FF;
      static constexpr unsigned_type mant_mask = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    };

    template<typename T>
    constexpr bool check_ieee754() {
        // add more check here
        return std::numeric_limits<T>::digits == (num::ieee754_traits<sizeof(T)>::mant_size + 1) &&
           std::numeric_limits<T>::max_exponent == (num::ieee754_traits<sizeof(T)>::exp_mask - num::ieee754_traits<sizeof(T)>::exp_shift);
    }
}
```

Then, you can check your representation:

```
static_assert(sizeof(float) == 4 && sizeof(double) == 8);
static_assert(num::check_ieee754<float>(), "does not match ieee754");
static_assert(num::check_ieee754<double>(), "does not match ieee754");
```

Comment: Why is this answer accepted? Did you try it? The C++ standard does not define anything called `ieee754_traits`, unless it is a new addition, and defining this structure yourself will not help you distinguish the built-in types.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, it boils down to "are there other IEC559/IEEE754 formats besides `binary32` which also have a 24 bits mantissa"? The answer to that is No.

You need the `iec559` part as that's what connects the C++ standard to the IEC standard. Without it, anything goes. Knowing it's IEC559, the `digits` test is straightforward.

But you want to make sure that the "24" is actually counted in bits, so you would want to check `radix==2` as well. That's the binary in `binary32`. Alternatively, you can check if `sizeof(float)*CHAR_BIT==32`. If `radix` is larger than two, you can't fit 24 digits in 32 bits.

Comment: I do not think this is correct. Only one of IEEE-754’s basic formats has a 24-bit significand, but it allows implementations to provide additional formats.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: True, but if you have another format with 24 digits and a non-binary radix, it won't fit in 32 bits. Even pow(3,24)>pow(2,32).

Comment: `float` is not necessarily 32 bits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: True, which is why I now suggest to see if the radix is 2, or the size is indeed 32 bits. The challenge with this question seems to be what properties must necessarily be different for an alternative format.